# 2-column book view in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**What I intend to do:** I have got a HTML content from an external source, which I need to display as a 2-column (horizontal scrolling) book view in my app, it will be through a WebView element. Similar to how Edge browser renders an EPUB book, and on clicking the left/right margin the entire screen width is scrolled horizontally, giving a feel of page turn.

[image]

**What I have done so far:** I have achieved close to similar effect by making an infinite width `div` and putting the external HTML content in another `div` and using `column-width` to have two columns on the screen, hid the scroll bars and `onClick` event of the left or right margins scroll the screen-width left or right. This seems kind of hacky to me as on scrolling the 2-column is not centrally aligned correctly.

Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/j2bdtwuf/9/

**Problem:** But when the window is resized, the columns are re-adjusted and then the view no longer has 2-columns in center, it messes-up completely with view being something like - half-column:full-column:half-column. Try scrolling a little in the sample fiddle link and then reduce the window size, you'll understand what I am trying to say.

What I want is, the two columns in the view remains static always, and when resized their content changes, but the column position in the view doesn't change.

**Question:** My current solution obviously looks hacky, is there a better way to achieve what I have stated above? **{1}** On scrolling the columns remain center positioned, **{2}** On Window resize the column contents change but the column position remains center positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try using min-width and min-height instead of width and height in your css.  That way the column will adjust themselves when the window is resized. (I haven't tested but it can help)

But if you really want a better approach, you could use bootstrap. Just add the CDN in yor page like it's explained [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/).

And then take a look at the grid system [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

Bootstrap is fully responsive and it will make your page look better. Good luck!